# FAT to ntfs on an empty disk

Tags: ntfs, 19.04, fat32

Is it possible to convert FAT to ntfs on empty disk with Linux commands or windows is the only option?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to convert FAT to nfts. As a graphical solution, you can install gparted, a partitioner on ubuntu. You just have to choose your empty disk and do a right-click on the empty space. Then choose **Format to** and click on NFTS. If you are finish, click on **Apply changes**.

I think you can also use `fdisk` program in the linux terminal. Type `sudo fdisk-l` to see the name of your device (empty disk). Then you have to type `mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb`. Change `sdb` with the device name of your empty disk.

Comment: Do not format entire drive like sdb, but only partitions like sdb1 or sdb2. Best not to use NTFS unless you have Windows. It will need chkdsk or defrag and you cannot do those from Linux. At least have a Windows repair disk if you really need NTFS.